# Rails 4 has_many through with condition, joining same table twice

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many

I have 3 models, User, Division and Staff. Staff belongs to User & Division respectively and stored a value called role. There are currently 2 roles which are "1" and "2". Below is my relationship.

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :staffs, :dependent => :destroy

  # manager view
  has_many :manage_divisions, -> { where staffs: { role: 1 } }, :through => :staffs, :source => :division
  has_many :manage_division_staffs, :through => :manage_divisions, :source => :staffs

  # staff view
  has_many :work_for_divisions, -> { where staffs: { role: 2 } }, :through => :staffs, :source => :division
  has_many :work_for_division_staffs, :through => :work_for_divisions, :source => :staffs
end
```

I want to get the divisions which the user manage through the staff table by User.manage_divisions. Then get the staff list of those divisions by User.manage_division_staffs. But now when I call User.manage_division_staffs, what return seems the staffs with role = 1 of the divisions(but not all staffs). Also I want to do something similar for User.work_for_divisions.

Below is the sql query generated when I called User.manage_division_staffs:

```
SELECT "staffs".* 
FROM "staffs" 
INNER JOIN "divisions" ON "staffs"."division_id" = "divisions"."id" 
INNER JOIN "staffs" "staffs_manage_division_staffs_join" ON "divisions"."id" = "staffs_manage_division_staffs_join"."division_id" 
WHERE "staffs"."role" = 1 
AND "staffs_manage_division_staffs_join"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 3]]
```

I know what I am doing wrong but I don't know the way to correct it. Any ideas??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, looks like you already have it set up for `work_for_division_staffs`

Comment: You specify `where staffs: { role: 1 }`, so why are you surprised that "what return seems the staff with role = 1."?

Comment: I want to get the divisions which the user manage through the staff table through User.manage_divisions. Then get the staff list of those divisions through User.manage_division_staffs. How can I achieve this?